# Parsing non-conventional dates in R

Tags: r, date, datetime

I hope you guys are having a good night.

I have a dataset that looks something like this:

```
data1
       [date]    [fuel_price] 
[1,]  201004         3.56           
[2,]  201105         3.32          
[3,]  201106         3.45           
[4,]  201212        3.94        
[4,]  201301         3.94
```

The dates are in the format of: YYYYMM, and I'm trying to have R interpret it that way. 
Here is my code so far:

```
DateNum = as.numeric(as.POSIXct(data1$date, format="%Y%m"))

PriceFun = approxfun(thedata1$fuel_price ~ DateNum)

PriceFromDate = function(x) {
  round(PriceFun(x), 3) }
```

Any reason why it isn't working for me?

Thank you guys in advanced.

Comment: "The dates are in the format of: YYYYMM" What about `2012012`? Also, a datetime class must include a day. Otherwise you don't have a date. You could try `as.numeric(as.POSIXct(paste0(data1$date, "01"), format="%Y%m%d"))` but the problem with your fourth line remains.

Comment: Also, you should probably use `as.Date` instead of `as.POSIXct` since the latter is seconds since epoch, i.e., a rather large number.

Comment: That was a typo, sorry about that! I'll try adding days and see if it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's rather risky approach but you could consider making use of the [**`anytime`**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/anytime/anytime.pdf) package:

```
  x <- c(201004,           
         201105,          
         201106,           
         2012012,        
         201301)  

  anytime::anytime(x, asUTC = TRUE)
```

this would give you:

```
[1] "2010-04-01 01:00:00 BST" "2011-05-01 01:00:00 BST" "2011-06-01 01:00:00 BST"
[4] "2012-12-01 00:00:00 GMT" "2013-01-01 00:00:00 GMT"
```

---

*The points discussed in comments are valid, you may first prefer to arrive at unambiguous strings making conscious assumptions about the date format; like assuming first day of a month for each date and the undertaking your conversions; the provided solutions uses your initial string `2012012` **with typo** to demonstrate that anytime would manage this string as well.*